# Addthis not loading on ajax content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, addthis

I am trying to load addthis button on dynamically loaded content but even though the script is loaded addthis toolbar doesnt appear.

```
jQuery(".somediv").html(response); // dynamically loaded content
jQuery.getScript("//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-53a011f32e6cd338")
    .done(function () {
        addthis.init();
        addthis.toolbox('.addthis_sharing_toolbox');
    })
```

And below is the html content

```
<div class="addthis_sharing_toolbox"></div>
```

Please help.

Comment: Have you included jquery in the page?

Comment: You mean to say in the ajax loaded content??

Comment: No. In the head section you need to include the jquery library before you can access any jquery feature

Comment: it is included in the head section

Comment: Could you post the full code?

Comment: jQuery(".somediv").html(response); This div contains the addthis toolbar. after the div is loaded with cotent iam calling jQuery.getScript("//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-53a011f32e6cd338")
.done(function() {
addthis.init();
addthis.toolbox('.addthis_sharing_toolbox');
});

Comment: Can you replicate your problem in a jsfiddle?

Comment: Please share the html that is being included through "response" variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@amit I was facing the same problem as you. After some research, I rooted the source of this problem.

If you added your addthis button through the dashboard, there is some shortcut html/js codes to add them in your site very quickly:

```
<!-- Go to www.addthis.com/dashboard to customize your tools -->
<div class="addthis_sharing_toolbox"></div>
```

But the formal way as the [addthis api doc](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381238-addthis-toolbox) states to add the buttons to you site is like:

```
<div class="addthis_toolbox" data-url="domain.com" data-title="title">
    <a class="addthis_button_facebook" style="cursor:pointer"></a> 
    <a class="addthis_button_twitter" style="cursor:pointer"></a> 
    <a class="addthis_button_email" style="cursor:pointer"></a>
</div>
```

So, if you add the following lines inside your div box of class 'addthis_sharing_toolbox', it will finally work.

```
<a class="addthis_button_facebook" style="cursor:pointer"></a> 
<a class="addthis_button_twitter" style="cursor:pointer"></a> 
<a class="addthis_button_email" style="cursor:pointer"></a>
```

Comment: The addthis_sharing_toolbox code is for our dashboard configuration tools, while the code you added is for our advanced configuration tools. We are working on enabling AJAX for our dashboard configuration tools.

Comment: @Paul Is there now APIs for this?

Answer (score 2):

**Step-1:** Put the following code into the main template from where you will call the ajax and also display the output:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=**YOUR-PUB-ID**" async="async"></script>
//So that, we are inserting this AddThis JS source only for once;
```

**Step-2:** the dynamic (ajax) content should have the following addthis lines with other content:

```
<div class="addthis_sharing_toolbox">
    <a class="addthis_button_email" style="cursor:pointer"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_facebook" style="cursor:pointer"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_twitter" style="cursor:pointer"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_linkedin" style="cursor:pointer"></a>
</div>
```

**Step-3:** Finally, after successful ajax load run the following line of code with the callback function;

```
addthis.toolbox('.addthis_sharing_toolbox');
```

For example:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: MY_URL,
    //......
    success: function(data){
        //......
        $("#MY-DIV").html(data); //THIS IS IMPORTANT TO INSERT THE DYNAMIC DATA INTO THE DOM BEFORE CALLING THE FOLLOWING TRIGGER;
        addthis.toolbox('.addthis_sharing_toolbox');
    }
});
```