# addthis share button not working when I open the modal twice

Tags: javascript, html, addthis

I'm using addthis share button in my website, but the click of the button is in a modal that is loaded dynamically, so when the modal html is loaded, I call the script of addthis this way:

```
  var addthisScript = document.createElement('script');
    addthisScript.id = 'addthisscript';
    addthisScript.setAttribute('src', 
    '//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#domready=1')
    document.body.appendChild(addthisScript);
```

So, when I open the modal at first time, it works!

But, if I close the modal and open again and click the button to share again, it just reload the page.

After reloaded the page, starts to work again, but just once.

I already try remove the script from DOM and create again, but still doesn't work!!

When the modal is closed, I remove the entire HTML, this way:

```
$(`#${id_modal}`).on("hidden.bs.modal",() => {
    $(`#${id_modal}`).remove();
}
```

And every time that I open the modal, I call the function addthis() that create the script above.

Any help?

Comment: Done. @Huangism

Comment: I am not sure exactly how the addthis script works but the way you are adding the script tag, if you are doing that every time you open the modal, you would end up with numerous script tags with the same script. Have you checked console for errors? I imagine you probably get errors the second time around. I think you only need to add that script once and maybe initialize it on the newly added button in the modal but again I am not sure how addthis works and you might not even need to initialize it once the script is there

Comment: I already tried remove the script when the modal was closed, to avoid create numerous script tags, but still doesn't work.
I already tried too to put the script tag just once, but the modal html is loaded dynamically, so there's no effect.
Console don't show any error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24553310/addthis-not-loading-on-ajax-content check that as it creates the button dynamically, maybe you just need to match the markup